# Maven build pushing jars instead of docker images

Tags: docker, maven-plugin

I have a maven project which builds a jar and then creates docker image. I am using spotify dockerfile maven plug-in to build. When I try to push the docker image, jar file is being pushed to the repository instead of docker image. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

By default maven artifact is a jar unless you set it differently.

You probably need to use [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Your question is lack of code snippets and useful information so I'm only assuming this is what you need.